# How to install AMD drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: amd-graphics

I am using HP Pavilion G series Model. I've been trying to install the AMD Catalyst driver on my laptop but it's not working.

Please give me a step-by-step procedure to install the AMD driver.

Answer (score 0):

Fglrx is no longer supported. The default Amd drivers are open source    now. Trying to get proprietary drivers from amd could possibly harm your system. For a variety of reasons including the potential of dated and incompatible drivers etc...

Type

```
man radeon
```

in the terminal. Scroll to the very bottom of list that's output you'll see something along the lines of

```
X11   xf86-video-ati 7.7.0
```

Because the drivers should already be installed.

Answer (score -1):

First of all check your AMD graphics card model by running the following command.

```
lspci | grep AMD
```

It will show you some result as (as mine does):

```
Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
```

After that, go to http://support.amd.com/en-us/download and check the driver for your system, download and install it.

Comment: thankx Mr.VPN,I am a new user to ubuntu that is why can you guide me step by step because i tried more then 15 times to intall amd drivers that was not success.

Comment: can you please provide your model no of hp pavilion G* series

Comment: HP pavilion g6 Version: F.41
 Version: 0696120000004610000600000
 Version: 09.47
 Version: Chassis Version
 SBDS Version: 1.1
 Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz

Comment: give your answer soon as posible